# How to add post fields on the basis of result of elastic search

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, elasticsearch

Actually i want to add "is_promoted" field in the response according to the result of elastic search if the "doc_count" is 1 then i have to fetch the id of the property and "is_promoted" flag from the actual result(Which you can see at the question).Its like a post filter in the elastic search. but i want add condition in the post filter. please see the current and expected output.
And below is the **current output** of the elastic query

```
 {
    "total_records": 32392,
    "fetched_records": 3845,
    "result": [
        {
            "key": "dp3w",
            "doc_count": 343,
            "centroid": {
                "location": {
                    "lat": 41.919059987131064,
                    "lon": -87.71653202438385
                },
                "count": 343
            }
        },
        {
            "key": "djvw",
            "doc_count": 1,
            "centroid": {
                "location": {
                    "lat": 33.49416188221888,
                    "lon": -82.0443208285174
                },
                "count": 1
            }
        },
        {
            "key": "9qhs",
            "doc_count": 1,
            "centroid": {
                "location": {
                    "lat": 34.52696419113244,
                    "lon": -117.29711956000672
                },
                "count": 1
            }
        }
] 
}
```

So i want to add field "is_promoted" if the "doc_count" is 1 and below is the **expected output**

```
 {
    "total_records": 32392,
    "fetched_records": 3845,
    "result": [
        {
            "key": "dp3w",
            "doc_count": 343,
            "centroid": {
                "location": {
                    "lat": 41.919059987131064,
                    "lon": -87.71653202438385
                },
                "count": 343
            }
        },
        {
            "key": "djvw",
            "doc_count": 1,
            "is_promoted":true,
            "centroid": {
                "location": {
                    "lat": 33.49416188221888,
                    "lon": -82.0443208285174
                },
                "count": 1
            }
        },
        {
            "key": "9qhs",
            "doc_count": 1,
            "is_promoted":true,
            "centroid": {
                "location": {
                    "lat": 34.52696419113244,
                    "lon": -117.29711956000672
                },
                "count": 1
            }
        }
] 
}
```

I used aggregation for that.

```
                    query.bool.minimum_should_match = 1;
                aggQuery.zoomedin = {
                    filter: {
                        geo_bounding_box: {
                            location: {
                                top_left: {
                                    lat: params.geo_bounding_box.location.nw.lat,
                                    lon: params.geo_bounding_box.location.nw.lng
                                },
                                bottom_right: {
                                    lat: params.geo_bounding_box.location.se.lat,
                                    lon: params.geo_bounding_box.location.se.lng
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    aggregations: {
                        result: {
                            geohash_grid: {
                                field: "location",
                                precision: zoomLevel
                            },
                            "aggs": {
                                "centroid": {
                                    "geo_centroid": { "field": "location" }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

Below is the record structure in my elastic search. I hope it will help you to understand the senario

```
"hits": {
"total": 7967,
"max_score": 1,
"hits": [
  {
    "_index": "biproxi-test",
    "_type": "listings",
    "_id": "5126",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
      "address_line1": "Brandon Town Center Drive",
      "address_line2": "USA",
      "building_class": null,
      "building_type": null,
      "built_year": null,
      "cap_rate": null,
      "category": 1,
      "city": "Brandon",
      "country": "United States",
      "county": "Hillsborough",
      "floor_location": null,
      "inplace_occupancy": null,
      "land_size": 3,
      "lease_type_id": null,
      "lease_type": null,
      "listing_group": "Retail",
      "listing_type": [
        1
      ],
      "location": {
        "lat": 27.937159,
        "lon": -82.327498
      },
      "no_of_units": null,
      "postal_code": "33511",
      "price": 2185000,
      "renovated_year": null,
      "square_feet": null,
      "state": "Florida",
      "state_code": "FL",
      "title": "3+- Acres at Brandon Town Center",
      "status": 2,
      "listing_image": "https://biproxi.s3.amazonaws.com/image/listing/5126/caf39154-fb42-483f-9320-9e9c394be66b.jpg",
      "seller_id": "113157245308689129523",
      "is_promoted": false
    }
  },      {
    "_index": "biproxi-test",
    "_type": "listings",
    "_id": "5213",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
      "address_line1": "1909 N. Columbia Street",
      "address_line2": "USA",
      "building_class": null,
      "building_type": null,
      "built_year": "1996",
      "cap_rate": null,
      "category": 2,
      "city": "Milledgeville",
      "country": "United States",
      "county": "Baldwin",
      "floor_location": null,
      "inplace_occupancy": null,
      "land_size": null,
      "lease_type_id": null,
      "lease_type": null,
      "listing_group": "Retail",
      "listing_type": [
        1
      ],
      "location": {
        "lat": 33.1086,
        "lon": -83.25388
      },
      "no_of_units": null,
      "postal_code": "31061",
      "price": null,
      "renovated_year": null,
      "square_feet": null,
      "state": "Georgia",
      "state_code": "GA",
      "title": "Milledge Village - 1 Space Remaining",
      "status": 2,
      "listing_image": "https://biproxi.s3.amazonaws.com/image/listing/5213/33d1cd5b-11a1-427d-8948-2e2db3d8e7f2.jpg",
      "seller_id": "113157245308689129523",
      "is_promoted": false
    }
  }
}]}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Are you simply trying to add the `is_promoted` field to the objects in the `result` array depending on a condition or are you trying to do something in Elasticsearch?

Comment: please mention clearly what is the issue you are facing

Comment: I have just edit my question i hope this will help you guys to understand the problem

Comment: @Milkncookiez Yes i want to add "is_promoted" field in the response according to the document_count in the cluster object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so, from the discussion in the direct comments under your OP I understand that you only want to add `is_promoted` field to some of the objects in the `result` array of the ES response, according to a certain condition.

What you need to do is very simple: loop through the `result` array, check the condition for each object and add the property.

```
for (const obj of elasticSearchResult.result) {
    if (+obj.doc_count <= 1) {
      obj['is_promoted'] = true;
    }
  }
```

I add the `+` sign in front of the `obj.doc_count` to ensure it's parsed to `int` and thus conducting a proper conditional comparison. The `is_promoted` property is added as an array key to ensure there are no compile or runtime errors of the sort of `Property does not exist`, since we create a new property in the object.

I don't know why do you use this aggregation functionality. You problem is purely JavaScript related and has nothing to do with ES or Node.js in particular.

P.S. This solution is based on the fact I understand your question correctly. Otherwise, please extend or improve your OP.

Comment: sorry . i just updated the question again. The situation is i have to add the "is_promoted" field if the aggregation response if the "doc_count" is 1. and that is_promoted flag comes from the actual result of the ES(Which you can see in the last part of my question where i posted actual json).